# Download Panoramio pictures

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, google-earth

Right now Panoramio is shut down by Google, according to 
[link](https://www.panoramio.com/)

However, when I open Google Earth, I can also find Panoramio photos. For example,

[image]

Is it possible to download these photos right now?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so easy. You just need to replace the number in this link:

> https://static.panoramio.com.storage.googleapis.com/photos/original/80554884.jpg

For example, you have opened in browser 'Comment it'

> http://www.panoramio.com/photo/55953867#comment

Just put 55953867 instead 80554884 in the first link.